# Maven jetty:run with filtering

Tags: maven, jetty, filtering, maven-jetty-plugin

Does anyone know how to use maven jetty:run with filtering? I've seen some other answers using other maven goals (jetty:run-exploded) but these don't let me modify my html pages on the fly without restarting.

Thanks.

Comment: My question is similar to this one (actually, basically the same issue, only with more details) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475811/who-to-filter-resources-when-using-maven-jetty-plugin

Answer (score 0):

afaik, with jetty:run it uses the source code's files, not the target.

you might need to run replacements on your source code files in a phase before you start jetty.

if you dont want replacements on your source files, i think you're stuck with run-exploded

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and posted an answer to my own stack overflow question, FYI: [How to filter resources when using maven jetty plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475811/who-to-filter-resources-when-using-maven-jetty-plugin)

Not sure whether I should duplicate that post, but I can if that's a requirement for acceptance.